# Complex Boolean simplification

Tags: boolean-algebra

> Simplify the following Boolean expression:
>   $$F=A'B'C'+A'B'C+A'BC'+AB'C'+AB'C.$$

I have tried and am getting stuck at $A'+B'+C'+A'BC'$.

According to the K-Map it should get to $B'+A'C'$.

Answer (score 1):

$F$ is NOT equal to 
$$A'+B'+C'+A'BC'=A'+B'+C'+A'BC'=A′+B′+C′(1+A′B)=A′+B′+C′.$$ 
If $A$ and $B$ are true and $C$ is false then $F$ is false whereas  $A′+B′+C′$ is true.

In order to simplify the given Boolean expression, note that  $A'B'C'=A'B'C'+A'B'C'$ and
\begin{align*}
F&=(A'B'C'+A'B'C+AB'C'+AB'C)+(A'BC'+A'B'C')\\
&=B'(A'(C'+C)+A(C'+C))+A'C'(B+B')\\
&=B'(A'+A)+A'C'=B'+A'C'\\
\end{align*}
where we used the fact that $A+A'=B+B'=C+C'=1$.

Comment: I cant get how you get to the first step

Comment: @Seffu Note that $A'B'C'=A'B'C'+A'B'C'$. Is it clear now?

Comment: is there a better editor for me o post the question as it is???

Comment: Hi Robert would there be any difference if some of the bars are continous???

Comment: F=A'+B'+C'+A'BC

Comment: @Seffu  $F$ is NOT equal to $A'+B'+C'+A'BC'$. See my edited answer.

Comment: I understood you.I am asking on how to simplify (A′+B′+C′+A′BC′)

Comment: @Seffu By the truth table $(A′+B′+C′+A′BC′)$ is true iff $A$,$B$,$C$ are all false hence it is equal to $A′+B′+C′$ or also $(ABC)'$. Another way: $$A′+B′+C′+A′BC′=A′+B′+C′(1+A′B)=A′+B′+C′.$$

Comment: @Seffu Any further doubts? BTW if you are new here take a few minutes for a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Thanks very much.I have just realized that the question  have is different from what I wrote because its not possible to type double or triple bars here

Comment: @Seffu What do you mean? Something like $\overline{AB}$ or $\overline{ABC}$ or $\overline{\overline{ABC}}$? Have you a web-link to this exercise?

Comment: yes something like that,how can I type those???

Comment: The command \overline{A} between dollars gives $\overline{A}$.

Comment: @Seffu If you are going to modify your problem I suggest you to ask a new question. Once again, I encourage you to see: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

There is a handy equivalence rule called Adjacency:

**Adjacency**

$PQ + PQ' = P$

'Adjacency' is of course named after the fact that it reflects exactly what you do in a K-map: you group together adjacent cells in order to get a simpler expression.

Another very useful principle is called Reduction:

**Reduction**

$P + P'Q = P + Q$ (that is, in the context of $P$, the term $P'Q$ reduces to just $Q$)

Applied to your problem:

$$A'B'C'+A'B'C+A'BC'+AB'C'+AB'C= \text{ (Adjacency) }$$

$$A'B'+A'BC'+AB'= \text{ (Adjacency) }$$

$$B'+A'BC'\text{ (Reduction) }$$

$$B'+A'C'$$

If you didn't know these two equivalences yet ... put them in your toolbox immediately!

And here is one more:

**Absorption**

$P+PQ=P$

$P(P+Q)=P$

Comment: What will A'+B'+C'+A'BC' give me?

Comment: @Seffu That will be A'+B'+C' by Absorption. That is, the A' term 'absorbs' the A'BC' term. I'll add Absorption to the post: you definitely need to know that one as well if you want to become skilled at Boolean algebra